# Riverpod state change methods not changing the state as intended

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

So I have a state in riverpod which holds a List of sets then I have two methods that make it a List of all the sets in the database and another that makes the state only today sets as follows:

```
u/riverpod
class SetsProvider extends _$SetsProvider {
  u/override
  List<Set> build() {
    return [];
  }

  void refresh() async {

         final data = await SQLHelper.getAllSets();

          state = data.map((e) => Set.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }



  void getTodaySets() async {

       final data = await SQLHelper.getTodayItems();

      state = data.map((e) => Set.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
```

When I call

```
final list = ref.watch(setsProviderProvider);
```

it works perfectly

But when I try to change the state to return only todays items it just doesn't work:

```
  ref.read(setsProviderProvider.notifier).getTodaySets();
```

it just makes my list empty when I watch the setProvider after that. What could I be doing wrong?

here is my dbhelper class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'set_model.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class SQLHelper {
  //method to create table
  static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async {
    await database.execute("""CREATE TABLE sets(
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
      exerciseName TEXT,
      totalWeight TEXT,
      totalReps TEXT,
      date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      isFavorited INTEGER 
      )
      """);
    print('Database created');
  }

//method to open the database called db
  static Future<sql.Database> db() async {
    return sql.openDatabase('dbsets.db', version: 1,
        onCreate: (sql.Database database, int version) async {
      await createTables(database); //calling that create table method above
    });
  }

  static Future<int> insertSet(Set set) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //opening the database
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(now);
    //Changing the Date to now meaning ill make the date not required in a Set object
    set.date == formattedDate;

    final id = await db.insert('sets', set.toJson(), //toJson calls the map
        conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace);

    return id;
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getAllSets() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    return db.query('sets', orderBy: 'id');
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getTodayItems() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //get connection
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(now);
    final results =
        db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date = ?', [formattedDate]);
    print(results.toString());
    return results;
  }
}
```

And where I am trying to show the sets in Main.dart:

```
   child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: ref.watch(setsProviderProvider).length,
              itemBuilder: ((_, index) {
                ref.read(setsProviderProvider.notifier).getTodaySets();
                final list = ref.watch(setsProviderProvider);
                var set = list[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(set.exerciseName.toString()),
                  subtitle: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        set.totalWeight.toString(),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        set.totalReps.toString(),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First don't put database calls in during `build`, it might run multiple time.
You could put it in places such as `initState` or `main()`.

The list didn't update because the initial list is empty, `itemCount` is 0, so item builder of `ListView` is never called.

Update: I meant `Widget.build`, not provider `build`. The best practice is to call it in provider's build, but this would also change the provider to async provider.

```
itemBuilder: ((_, index) {
    ref.read(setsProviderProvider.notifier).getTodaySets(); // <- This shouldn't be here/
    final list = ref.watch(setsProviderProvider);
```

Comment: So I fix this by moving the database calls into main? How do I make the database call from the buttons on press if the database calls aren't in the build method?

Comment: Putting it in `onPress` is Ideal practice. I should have been more clear, it shouldn't be called during build process, but putting it in callbacks in `build` function is fine since it will only be called at later time.

Comment: Putting database calls in a provider's "build" method is entirely fine

Comment: I meant it shouldn't be used in `Widget.build`.  The given code sample uses `getTodaySets()` in `itemBuilder` @RémiRousselet

Comment: My mistake. I swear I thought this was inside a provider :P

Comment: Are you saying to move my two database call methods( getTodaySets() and refresh() ) in my provider into its build method? How would I then retrieve getYesterdaySets() and get ThisMonthsSets in different widgets in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the filter provider *watch* the full-list provider, as well as take a filter argument as a family key.  Then, as you update the full-list provider (either from local mutations, or from watching a database stream), the filter provider(s) will have the proper value, caching as long as they are being watched.

Comment: Can you show me how I would do this. I don't understand which is the filter provider? I only have one provider here with different methods mutating the state

Comment: Examples of this are in the riverpod documentation.